# $(...).material_chip is not a function only in chrome

Tags: materialize

I use jquery-3.2.1.js and  Materialize v0.98.2 (http://materializecss.com)
i had this code html `<div class="chips chips-initial"></div>` and
this code of js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

//$('.chips').material_chip()

$('.chips-initial').material_chip({
    data: [{
      tag: 'Apple',
    }, {
      tag: 'Microsoft',
    }, {
      tag: 'Google',
    }],
  });
```

});

in IE work, firefox too but in chrome i had this error:
jquery-3.2.1.js:3869 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_chip is not a function

---

#### Solved

I just delete all chrome cache, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Materialize currently only supports jQuery 2.1.4, but we plan on supporting jQuery 3 soon
Ref: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/pull/4587

Comment: the probleme was in chrome cache now it work even with jquery jquery-3.2.1.js, thank you